# Direct Import of gziped (.gz) files in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

My data is stored in `.CSV` file. I'm trying to find an efficient method for directly importing `.csv.gz` files.

In my current process, I'm loading these files via Python and then using the ORM. However, I'm finding this approach less efficient than I'd prefer.

Is there a native feature or perhaps a workaround in Memgraph that allows for the direct import of .tsv.gz files? Or could you suggest a more efficient way to handle this kind of data import beyond using Python and the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LOAD CSV](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/load-csv) clause works well with CSV's which are compressed with `gzip` or `bzip2`.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "/country.csv.gz" WITH HEADER AS row
CREATE (c:country) SET c += row;
```